# Mono c# embedding, mono_runtime_invoke crash app

Tags: c#, c++, mono, nullreferenceexception

I'm embedding Mono to my c++ app. And I'm having problems with `mono_runtime_invoke()`.

Here is the method that calls `mono_runtime_invoke`:

```
void CSScript::CallFunction(MonoMethod * function, void ** parameter)
{
   inside_function = true;
   MonoObject* exception = nullptr;

   MonoObject* obj = mono_runtime_invoke(function, mono_object, parameter, &exception);

   if (exception)
   {
       mono_print_unhandled_exception(exception);
   }
}

//---------------------

CallFunction(start, nullptr);
```

And here the c# funtion I'm calling (Start()):

```
public class Nngf 
{
   void Start ()
   {
       GameObject go = null;
       go.SetName("Hi!");
   }
}
```

As you can see, the Start method is calling a method (SetName) from a null class (Gameobject) and I should get a NullReference exception in the c++ CallFunction() method. But instead, the app crashes:

[image]

I have tested the c# script in Unity and I'm getting the NullReference error.

What I need to do? I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I just had to deactivate the option "Break when this exception is thrown" and app continues and I can get the exception message.